# How to redirect a page in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

Hello I'm trying to navigate a page `by code behind` in Xamarin.iOS. 
How can I do this ?

I searched the web and couldn't find a solution.

This is what I have tried so far but this code doen't work :

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main",null);
var nextViewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("Page2") as Page2;
PresentViewController(nextViewController, true, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one :

```
var nextViewController = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main",NSBundle.MainBundle).InstantiateViewController("Page2") as Page2;

ShowViewController(nextViewController, this);
```

Comment: @mrbengi true its just an parameter that says that we want to animate transition between pages.

Comment: @mrbengi oh sorry,it's was a typo. try again my answer.(i have updated). Not true,but "this".